# Нужна помощь с Web чатом на Java и WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, spring, mvc, websocket

Сама настройка веб сокета

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Есть метод контроллера который отвечает за отправку сообщения в очередь

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void chatting(MessageDto message) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
    message.setFormatDate(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    Message saveMessage = messageService.saveMessage(message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chat/" + saveMessage.getConversation().getUIDConversation(), message);
}
```

т.е. по задумке у меня для пары пользователей свой уникальный канал.
Всё работает отлично если оба пользователя нажали на иконки друг друга на UI, получается что они оба подписываются на один и тот же канал созданный для них.
Проблема заключается в том, если нажмет на иконку только один пользак и будет писать сообщения другому, который не нажал на иконку чата, то получается, что он в очереди один и сообщения уйдёт в никуда.
Есть ли какой нибудь способ уведомить пользователя, что ему пришло сообщение или же как нибудь его автоматом подключить к очереди начавшего разговор юзера?
На всякий случай код коннекта js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chat_list').click(function () {
            var idClickUser = this.id;
            UIDConversation = currentUserId + idClickUser;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/chat/check',
                data: {
                    idClickUser: idClickUser,
                    currentUserId: currentUserId,
                    UIDConversation: UIDConversation
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    connect(UIDConversation);
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        if (value.name === userName) {
                            printMsg(value.msg, value.formatDate);
                        } else {
                            showMessage(value.name, value.msg, value.formatDate);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

function connect(chatUID) {
        var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chat/' + chatUID, function (message) {
                showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body).name,
                    JSON.parse(message.body).msg,
                    JSON.parse(message.body).formatDate);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Вам известен логин второго пользователя? Если да, то можно определить подключен ли он к веб сокету. Если нет то послать ему сообщение (именно ему, личное сообщение) в котором передать инфу о топике.

Comment: @Tsyklop для этого достаточно будет использовать messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("UserName", "/topic/chat/" + saveMessage.getConversation().getUIDConversation(), message); или ещё нужны какие то настройки?